# What is limit of genrating access token for Microsoft Graph API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I want to know that, is there any restriction on generating no. of access tokens when working with Microsoft Graph API per day. Lets say I have concurrent jobs running at my machine which generates access tokens, will it be scenario that I will run in problems saying you have reached maximum limit of generating access tokens?

Regards,
Amit.

Comment: Please edit your question and explain what you mean by `limit`?

Comment: Since the token is valid for an hour by default, you shouldn't be requesting a new one all the time.

Comment: There may be some limit, but I've never hit it.

Comment: The is no defined limit, but you could be throttled with 429s. Program for those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know, there is no this limit for generating access_token.  For the related Azure AD service limits, you could refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits#active-directory-limits).

Comment: Thanks Sunny, it helps!

Comment: If it is useful for you, please mark the answer, thanks for the help!